# Extending Identity 2.1 to assign user to company and roles to users

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Ok so i am really lost now,

I have an application that works great, i have groups of data that are available to a company subscription, When the user logs in they can access the information from the data that their roles allow, If they have multiple roles they have access to multiple areas of reports, if they only subscribe to one role they only have access to that one area. now all the data is the same and updated daily, so if 100 users are subscribed to roles 1,3 and 5 they can access that data. for the last decade the users of the companies would use one login to access the data ( one login supplied to company for George, But Lisa, john, Jerry and bob all use George's credentials to download reports). Note the data does not change per company and the site does not change per company all data and themes are part of the one site they have access to.

Now the Issue.

I have been asked by many of my users (Companies that access my data) that they would like to be able to to add users to their account so they can monitor who is downloading what report as i charge subscription by 500, 1000, and 2000 reports. My application records reports downloaded and the user can view these reports from their user portal and the id that downloaded it. the issue is that the companies want to be able to administer their own users, sort of like an account admin. I have looked into multi tenant and this does not really suit my needs, but from what i am looking at **i feel i need to add a company_id to the user and company_id user roles** so each company can have an admin role and a user role. but not sure as i study and read more on this i see allot of different ideas. but dont really see one that works for me.

here is an example.

Each user (company) has many users, each user in that company has roles of Admin or user. Users (companies) have access to many areas that roles allow them and the users of that company would have the same access to reports tha company roles provide. (or see aggregate data across all groups they belong to).

Thinking of adding this to IdentityModels:

```
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>//, IAppUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public virtual string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CompanyEntity> Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

add to IdentityConfig:

```
public string GetCurrentCompanyId(string userName)
    {
        var user = this.FindByName(userName);
        if (user == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var currentCompany = string.Empty;
        if (user.Claims.Count > 0)
        {
            currentCompany = user.Claims.Where(c => c.ClaimType == ConcordyaPayee.Core.Common.ConcordyaClaimTypes.CurrentCompanyId).FirstOrDefault().ClaimValue;
        }
        else
        {
            currentCompany = user.CurrentCompanyId;
        }
        return currentCompany;
    }

    public override Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(string userId, string role, string companyId)
    {
        return base.AddToRoleAsync(userId, role);
    }
```

Now im not sure about this, do i need to create a new user store. and how would authentication work, will i need to write a new Authorize Attribute. should i be using the claims. or maybe ACL system. or do i need to find a different identity provider.

Any help would be appreciated greatly. as i am getting very confused.